# I can not use vegan in R

Tags: r, require, vegan

I am trying to open the library vegan in R but I have this message:

> library(vegan)
> Loading required package: permute
> Loading required package: lattice
> This is vegan 2.5-7
> Warning messages:
> 1: package ‘vegan’ was built under R version 4.1.3
> 2: package ‘permute’ was built under R version 4.1.3
> 3: package ‘lattice’ was built under R version 4.1.3

What is this caused by and what can I do to resolve the problem indicated by this diagnostic message?

Comment: These are warning messages - not errors. It should still work. You can get rid of the warnings, by updating your copy of R.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do that